# How to add text to a inkcanvas with code?

Tags: wpf, inkcanvas

I would like to add some text (like a label) on a InkCanvas with WPF in C# code (not Xaml).

How is it possible ?
thanks
Jonathan

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this. (See MSDN docs for SetTop, SetLeft)

```
// add control to children collection 
// (ctlToAdd can be TextBlock, RichTextBox, FlowDocument for example
inkCanvas.Children.Add(ctlToAdd);
InkCanvas.SetTop(ctlToAdd, 100.0);
InkCanvas.SetLeft(ctlToAdd,100.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to implement a custom Stroke class and use Drawingcontext.DrawString method for the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void drawTextBox(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)  
{  
TextBox = new TextBox();  
myInkCanvas.Children.Add(myTextBox);  
myTextBox.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;  
Point mousePos = e.GetPosition(myInkCanvas);  
double left = Math.Min(mouseDownPos.X, mousePos.X);  
double top = Math.Min(mouseDownPos.Y, mousePos.Y);  
myTextBox.Width = Math.Abs(mouseDownPos.X - mousePos.X);  
myTextBox.Height = Math.Abs(mouseDownPos.Y - mousePos.Y);  
InkCanvas.SetLeft(myTextBox, left);  
InkCanvas.SetTop(myTextBox, top);  
}
```

you can get mouseDownPos in :

```
private void myInkCanvas_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(objectsender,MouseButtonEventArgs){  
mouseDownPos = e.GetPosition(myInkCanvas);  
}
```

This is a simple code that you can use it in your program.

Answer (score 0):

There is a regular Children property:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.children.aspx

Check the examples for a code example

Comment: Hi, Thanks. But looks like the positionning does not work. it always put it on top 100,100 even if of course i changed the parameters

Comment: Could you edit you question and add some sample xaml and code-behind?